# Shrinkwrap wraps itself on the inside of the mesh

Tags: modeling, mesh, properties, shrinkwrap

Whenever I try shrink wrapping a plane to a mesh, the plane wraps itself IN the mesh instead of wrapping it OUTSIDE the mesh.

[image: Outside mesh]

[image: Inside mesh]

[image: Shrinkwrap properties]

How can I stop this from happening?
Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried to change the Offset?

Comment: I have tried changing the offset but unfortunately it does not change the way it looks (it keeps the same shape as if it is still on the inside of the mesh)